# LocalNotification plugin phonegap doesn't work on IOS?

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I am trying to develop an application that show me a notification i m using katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications and intel xdk IDE when i build app in Android and install .apk file in my phone it works fine but when i build the same application for ios and install .ipa in iphone then notification not working.

This is my code

```
function test(){

        var msg = document.getElementById("myText").value;
         if(msg==''){
        msg='Please Take flower..';
        }
         var date = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
         var time = document.getElementById("myTime").value;

       var now = new Date(date+' '+time).getTime(),  _60_seconds_from_now=new Date(now+1*1000);

      window.plugin.notification.local.add(
      {
      id:      1,
      title:   'title',
      message: msg,
      repeat:  'daily',
      date:      _60_seconds_from_now
     });

   navigator.notification.alert('Successfully Add Notification',null,"Notification ","OK!" );

    }

    and HTML Code is

   <div data-role="page" id="page" >
    <div id="hed5" data-role="header" >
        <h3>
          heder
        </h3>
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow      ui-corner-all"  data-role="button" role="button" id="bckbtn">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
```

```
<input type="date" id="date"><br>   


    <input type="time" id="time"><br>


     <input type="text" id="text">

   </div>
  <br/>
   <div class="center-button"><button type="submit" id="dr"   onclick="test()" data-mini="true" style="font-style: oblique">notify</button></div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: It looks like there are a few special cases for iOS on the doc page, e.g. support for iOS8 isn't released yet (at least that's the way I read it) and maybe some other conditions that might affect you.  Have you checked those carefully? - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide Thanks for your response i have tried on ios7.1 also but notification does not appeare